# Finding a value $\alpha$ such that a function $c$ is a copula density of $(U_1, U_2)$

Tags: probability-distributions, copula

Let
$$c(u_1,u_2) = 1 + \alpha(1- 2u_1)(2- 2u_2)$$
where $u_1, u_2 \in (0,1)$.

The question is, for which $\alpha$ is the function $c$ a copula density for $(U_1, U_2)$.

So my idea was to compute the integral of $c$ on $[0,1]^2$, and see for which $\alpha$ is the integral equal to 1. But
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 c(u_1,u_2)\ du_1 du_2 = 1$$
for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. The answer is apparently $\alpha \in [-1,-1]$, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

There must be a mistake in your question formulation because what you present cannot be a copula. For one, a copula should satisfy

$$u_1=C(u_1,1)=\int_0^1 c(u_1,u_2)du_2 = 1+\alpha(1-2u_1)$$

But this can not be satisfied for any value of $\alpha$.

I suspect what you meant was to check if

$$c(u_1,u_2) = c(u_1,u_2) = 1 + \alpha(1- 2u_1)(1- 2u_2)$$

is a copula. Note the difference in the second factor of the second term.

In that case, checking that this is a copula density corresponds to checking the conditions of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Definition). Note that the first two conditions are trivial to check. The third condition is equivalent to checking that the density is positive. Now, $-1 \leq (1-2u_1)(1-2u_2) \leq 1$, thus the density can only be positive if $\alpha \in [-1,1]$.